# Issue with hosting lit-element based Web Component in angular 9 application

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, web-component, custom-element, lit-element

I have created a web component using lit-element, lit-html. It renders fine in modern browsers as well as in IE 11 using webcomponents-loader.js.

But the same web component if I load in Angular application, it just doesn't render.
Using the following script tags in the index.html file.

```
<script src="http://xxxx/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://xxxxxx/mycomponent.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="https://xxxxxxx/mycomponent.IE.js" nomodule=""></script>
```

Getting following errors

> SCRIPT28: Out of stack space

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this issue by importing core-js just before webcomponents.js

Reference from https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/968#issuecomment-402674742

I'm still trying to understand as if there are better options.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.5.7/core.min.js">   </script>
<script src="http://xxxx/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://xxxxxx/mycomponent.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="https://xxxxxxx/mycomponent.IE.js" nomodule=""></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you also need to transpile those modules to ES 5 to support legacy browsers like IE.

Below the information, I get from the Lit-element official site.

> To support older browsers that don’t support ES6 and the web
> components specifications, you’ll need to take a few extra steps to
> produce code that will run on the older browsers. There are two basic
> approaches you can take:
>
> - Build two versions of the project: a smaller, faster version for    modern browsers and a transpiled version with extra polyfills for
>   legacy browsers.
> - Build a single version of the project for all browsers. This is    simpler, but will be slower on modern browsers.
>
> At a high level, you need to do the following for your legacy build:
>
> - Compile to ES5. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is the most commonly used tool for this.
>
>   - You need to compile the lit-html and LitElement modules (from the node_modules folder) as well as your code.
>   - You need to transform JavaScript modules into a format compatible with older browsers, such as SystemJS, or a plain
>     JavaScript file that can be loaded in a  tag.
>   - Don’t bundle the Babel runtime polyfills in with your web component code. They should be bundled separately.
> - Load the requisite polyfills before loading your web components.
>
>   - Load the [Babel runtime polyfills](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) first.
>   - Load the [web components polyfills](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs).
>   - In almost all cases, you’ll also want to load [custom-elements-es5-adapter.js](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs#custom-elements-es5-adapterjs) to ensure that your ES5 version
>     can also run on newer browsers. You can load this file either before
>     or after the web components polyfills.

Reference:

[LitElement supporting older browsers](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/start#supporting-older-browsers)

Comment: the webcomponent I'm using is getting transpiled to ES5. I will check for other suggestions mentioned above